# How to get java to recognize symbolic links under cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin, symlink

Here's a very simple java program to print the first line of a file:

```
import java.io.*
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.print(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0])).readLine());
  }
}
```

When I run this program under cygwin and pass it the name of a symbolic link, it prints the contents of the symbolic link, not the target of that link:

```
$ echo foo > testfile
$ ln -s testfile symlink_to_testfile
$ java test testfile
foo
$ java test symlink_to_testfile
!<symlink> ?t e s t f i l e
```

How do I convince java to follow the symlink?  I was hoping there was something simpler than implementing the redirect myself.

Comment: I poked around and found a tool called Junction (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) which I used to make a shortcut under windows (instead of the ln -s above).  That seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple answer to this.  As various pages state, Cygwin is an application suite rather than an OS, and Sun does not support Java on Cygwin.

However, it *may* be possible to build JDK 6 for Cygwin from the source code.  Certainly, [this page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/build/README-builds.html) implies that it is possible.  Whether this gives you a JDK that understands Cygwin style symbolic links is anyones guess ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem too, so i wrote a shell wrapper that includes something like

```
# java runs as native windows program, so convert pathnames
WINDOWS_ARGS=""
for ARG in $*
do
if [ -e $ARG ]
# pathname argument is only converted if the file exists,
# so this trick may not be appropriate everywhere...
then
WINDOWS_ARGS="$WINDOWS_ARGS `cygpath -w $ARG`"
else
WINDOWS_ARGS="$WINDOWS_ARGS $ARG"
fi
done
java -jar `cygpath -w myprogram.jar` $WINDOWS_ARGS
```

because i'm invoking things from the cygwin shell anyway.  if you need to start the script from the window$ environment, see http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2004-07/msg00163.html

`cygpath` is the suggested way to convert path strings... i arrived at this page because i want to open a `File` object with a hardcoded path that may be a cygwin symlink.  still unsure about that one... running a subprocess seems extreme and requires either `cygpath` to be on your windows path or the cygwin directory to be in the same place on every computer.

Comment: Best answer in my opinion.  I've made a similar script based on yours.  It does not assume the `-jar` option and has no problems with arguments containing spaces.

Comment: This only works with file names specified on the command line. If the program constructs a file name, or reads the file name from somewhere else, and then tries to open it, it will still read the contents of the link instead of the linked-to file.

Answer (score 2):

I love derpaderp's answer so I adjusted it for my needs.  It is more general in not assuming a `-jar` option and not having problems with arguments containing spaces.  I've moved this script to `/usr/bin/java`  and made it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh    

JAVA_PATH="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/java"


declare -a WINDOWS_ARGS
i=0
for ARG in "$@"
do

    if [ -e "$ARG" ]; then
        # pathname argument is only converted if the file exists,
        # so this trick may not be appropriate everywhere...
        WINDOWS_ARGS[$i]="`cygpath -w $ARG`"
    else
        WINDOWS_ARGS[$i]="$ARG"
    fi
    (( i++ ))
done
"$JAVA_PATH" "${WINDOWS_ARGS[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Java you are using?  [This Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/links.html) indicates that NIO is aware of filesystem links, so you should be aok as long as you're Java1.4 or later.  It might be that it is actually nio2 it is talking about, in which case try it with the [Java7](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ea.jsp) pre-release.

Comment: This is with 1.6.0_20, HotSpot VM.  The package they recommend (java.nio.file) doesn't exist until Java7.  I don't think I want to go Java7 just yet.